# TinyMCE is changing my inline CSS

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

I input this in the HTML editor:

```
<p style="border:1px solid #edede4;border-top:none"></p>
```

I click update, and click the html editor again. The HTML (in Firefox) has changed to:

```
<p style="border-style: none solid solid; border-color: -moz-use-text-color rgb(237, 237, 228) rgb(237, 237, 228); border-width: medium 1px 1px;" mce_style="border:1px solid #edede4;border-top:none"><br></p>
```

If I do the same thing in Internet Explorer, the HTML changes to:

```
<P style="BORDER-RIGHT: #edede4 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: #edede4 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #edede4 1px solid" mce_style="border:1px solid #edede4;border-top:none">&nbsp;</P>
```

Why in the world does it change? Maybe there are some TinyMCE settings i can change? But I already have cleanup: false. Ideas?

If I enable cleanup, the change I'm mentioning doesn't happen. However, TinyMCE changes a lot of other stuff. I don't want it to mess with my code :( Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @anon, if you put your code on a new line and prefix it with 4 spaces, it will render as a code block on stackoverflow.  This way you will not need to put in the single quote.

Comment: Inline styling ("inline CSS" is a misnomer here) is a very bad practice, and rather against the flow of modern web dev - suggest you consider refactoring to stylesheets, beyond any tiymce solution

Comment: It's for editing a newsletter, and the experts say inline css is the way to go. It's beyond my control anyway.

Comment: beyond your control fair enough, but who are these experts?

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about what the editor presents.  When the form gets submitted, is the markup clean once it hits the server-side?

Comment: @John Stodola: I do believe it's the html in the frontend. I've used TinyMCE in Joomla and when you set "have cleanup: false", you have beautiful "mce_" attributes in your code.

Comment: +1 the question.  No amount of fiddling with anything in this thread  (and more) stops tinymce from stripping the inline 'style' attribute on my  input <p> element.  If anyone ever definitively solves this, please post!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `verify_html` to false.

Doc: [TinyMCE Configuration/verify_html](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/verify_html)

Comment: Having inline_styles set to true or false does not make any difference. The problem still persists :(

Comment: Try the other property listed above

Comment: Setting verify_html to false didn't help. :(

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes inline styles are neccessary as was the case for this project.
In this case I simply inserted html code piece by piece. Instead of inserting:

```
<p style="border:1px solid #edede4;border-top:none"></p>
```

I did something like this:

```
<p style=

"border:1px solid #edede4;border-top:none

"></p>
```

It's not perfect, but it works for this case as I don't want to change any TinyMCE settings. And it doesn't get recognised by TinyMCE as style code.

Answer (score 0):

When I have too many trouble with TinyMCE I just try to create other alternatives. The "correct" way is to create a class in you css.

Instead of:

```
<p style="border:1px solid #edede4;border-top:none"></p>
```

Use:

```
<p class="p_border"></p>
```

And declare in your css:

```
.p_border {
    border:1px solid #edede4;
    border-top:none;
}
```

Unfortunaly, you're doing a newsletter so you need inline. I haven't tested creating "style" tags before each "p" in this scenario with the class I declared above. You could try to see if it works.

If it doesn't work, I would try to use "inline_styles : true".